# Comparing some data of a file with another file in python

Tags: python, file, file-comparison

I do have a file f1 which Contains some text lets say "All is well".
In Another file f2 I have maybe 100 lines and one of them is "All is well".

Now I want to see if file f2 contains content of file f1.

I will appreciate if someone comes with a solution.

Thanks

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Provide your code so far and explain what your problem is? We don't do homework for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with open("f1") as f1,open("f2") as f2:
    if f1.read().strip() in f2.read():
         print 'found'
```

Edit:
As python 2.6 doesn't support multiple context managers on single line:

```
with open("f1") as f1:
    with open("f2") as f2:
       if f1.read().strip() in f2.read():
             print 'found'
```

Comment: can you please give a positive rating to my question I would really appreciate :), question can be found here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12138298/does-with-open-not-works-with-python-2-6

Comment: As Sara discovered, this only works in Python 2.7; in Python 2.6, you have to nest the `with` statements as multiple context managers on one line is not yet supported.

Answer (score 1):

```
template = file('your_name').read()

for i in file('2_filename'):
    if template in i:
       print 'found'
       break
```

Comment: if line should be absolutely the same you may use template == i

Comment: just a stylistic remark: use `i` for `integers`. here `s` or `l` is probably more suited.

Answer (score 0):

```
with open(r'path1','r') as f1, open(r'path2','r') as f2:
    t1 = f1.read()
    t2 = f2.read()
    if t1 in t2:
        print "found"
```

Using the other methods won't work if there's '\n' inside the string you want to search for.

Answer (score 0):

```
fileOne = f1.readlines()
fileTwo = f2.readlines()
```

now `fileOne` and `fileTwo` are list of the lines in the files, now simply check

```
if set(fileOne) <= set(fileTwo):
    print "file1 is in file2"
```