# Python: Opening multiple files using 'with open'

Tags: python, syntax-error, with-statement

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python: open multiple files using “with open”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4617034/python-open-multiple-files-using-with-open)
>   [Does, With open() not works with python 2.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12138298/does-with-open-not-works-with-python-2-6)

I have seen other answers to help me with this.
But I can't  seem to get any of the solutions provided to work at all!
Here is part of my code for it:

```
with open('Levels.dat', 'w') as l, open('Names.dat', 'w') as n:
```

I got this error:

```
    with open('Levels.dat', 'w') as l, open('Names.dat', 'w') as n:  
                                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: I keep trying to help you with your formatting. Please do not keep reverting it again.

Comment: Oh sorry about that, I'm trying to make it look how it is in my code

Comment: @junyi00: The `try:` line is not relevant, and I reproduced your error on Python 2.6, and adjusted the syntax error traceback to match that.

Comment: You tagged this with Python 2.7, but the syntax error you see would only happen in python 2.6.

Comment: Thx for that. I always thought that I used 2.7.3, I must look at it again